# Loop through array, show TextBox and wait for ENTER

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a view where the user should select some options with the keyboard.

Then a dynamic amount of values must be filled. For each value, a TextBox will be opened (should be the same every time), and if the user filled out, he press Enter, value will be saved and the next element in loop will be filled with the same procedure.

I dont want to open a modal dialog for that.

Here some pseudo code:

```
// ... some code
MyObject o = new MyObject();
foreach(entryToBeFilled in o.myList){
    mySampleInputBox.Text = ""
    mySampleInputBox.Visible = True;

    // ... some sort of waiting until user hits ENTER inside the InputBox

    entryToBeFilled = mySampleInputBox.Text;
}
mySampleInputBox.Visible = False;

// ... some code
```

I have no idea how to solve this requirement.

Comment: You can use the TextBox events, such as `TextChanged`

Comment: `// ...  some sort of waiting` how is this different to a modal dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
private int _listIndex = -1;
private IList<string> _listToFill = null;

private void StartFilling(IList<string> myList)
{
    if (!myList.Any())
        return;
    _listToFill = myList;
    _listIndex = 0;
    mySampleInputBox.Text = "";
    mySampleInputBox.Visible = true;
    mySampleInputBox.Focus();
}

private void mySampleInputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter)
        return;
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    _listToFill[_listIndex++] = tb.Text;
    tb.Text = "";
    if (_listIndex >= _listToFill.Count())
    {
        tb.Visible = false;
        _listIndex = -1;
        _listToFill = null;
    }
}
```

And whenever you want to start filling (and show the `TextBox`):

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();    
StartFilling(o.myList);
```

All this said, this is really a good candidate for a modal dialog, and unless there's something that you haven't said in your question, I'd go for one